# Opening a file with python in the same directory from different locations

Tags: python

I am currently accessing a script that opens a file in the directory it's located in. I am accessing this file from both the main.py file located in the same directory, as well as a testfile which is located in a "Test" subdirectory. Trying to use a file from the Test subdirectory to call the function that opens the file causes the script to try and open it from the Test directory instead of the super directory, since I am opening the file simply by calling it as following:

```
with open(filename,"w") as f:
```

Is there a way to define the location of the file in a way that makes it possible for the script opening it to be called from anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `__file__` to get the path to the current script file, then find the file relative to that:

```py
# In main.py: find the file in the same directory as this script
import os.path
open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'file.txt'))
```

```py
# In Test/test.py: find the file one directory up from this script
import os.path
open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'file.txt'))
```

Answer (score 2):

just give the `absolute file` path instead of giving a relative one

for eg

```
abs_path = '/home/user/project/file'
with open(abs_path, 'r') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the path:

```
import os
path = 'Your path'
path = os.path.abspath(path)  

with open(path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood your file is in a directory parent_directory/file_name.txt
and in  another folder parent_directory/sub_directory/file_name.txt. All you have to do is paste the below code in both parent and sub directories.

```
import os

file_name = 'your_file_name'
# if the file is in current directory set the path to file_name
if file_name in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    path = file_name
# if the path is not in current directory go back to parent directory set the path to parent directory
else:
    path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.pardir))
print('from',os.getcwd())
with open(path, 'r') as filename:
    print(filename.read())
```